# How to assign (use) input name to Uppy uploader when we have multiple uppy uploader

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, uppy

I am trying to use `Uppy` to upload some images in my `Laravel` application. I need multiple uppy elements in one page that each one upload one specific image. For example Uppy1 for upload Nationality Card image and Uppy2 for upload Drive Licence image. I use below code for upload images.

```
<script>
        const Dashboard = Uppy.Dashboard;
        const XHRUpload = Uppy.XHRUpload;

        var cls = '.kt_uppy';
        var options = {
            proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
            target: id,
            inline: true,
            resultName: 'uppyResult',
            replaceTargetContent: true,
            showProgressDetails: true,
            note: null,
            height: 170,
            metaFields: [
                { id: 'name', name: 'Name', placeholder: 'file name' },
                { id: 'caption', name: 'Caption', placeholder: 'describe what the image is about' }
            ],
            browserBackButtonClose: true,
        }

        var uppyDashboard = Uppy.Core({
            autoProceed: true,
            restrictions: {
                maxFileSize: 1000000, // 1mb
                maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                minNumberOfFiles: 1
            }
        });

        uppyDashboard.use(Dashboard, options);
        uppyDashboard.use(XHRUpload, {
            endpoint: '{{ route('upload') }}',
        })
```

**Problems:**

1 - Can we use and init multiple uppy elements just with write one code? (above code)
because number of persons that I need to get informations are Flexible. For ex: one family have 1 child and other family have 3 children and number of Nationality Card to upload is flexible

2 - How to assign different name attribute to each uppy element? like: `<input type="file" name"name1">` and `<input type="file" name"name2">`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Uppy id options](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#id-39-uppy-39)

you set id options in Uppy instance

then, you can control each Uppy instance separately

So, there are two ways for setting id

```js
const uppy = Uppy({id: 'new id'})

const uppy = Uppy()

uppy.setOptions({id: 'new id'})
```

so edit your code like below example

```html
   var uppyDashboard = Uppy.Core({
            autoProceed: true,
            restrictions: {
                maxFileSize: 1000000, // 1mb
                maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                minNumberOfFiles: 1
            }
        });
        
   
      var uppyOneDashboard = Uppy.Core({
            id: 'id 1',
            autoProceed: true,
            restrictions: {
                maxFileSize: 1000000, // 1mb
                maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                minNumberOfFiles: 1
            }
        });
        
    var uppyTwoDashboard = Uppy.Core({
            id: 'id 2',
            autoProceed: true,
            restrictions: {
                maxFileSize: 1000000, // 1mb
                maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                minNumberOfFiles: 1
            }
        });
```

then, you have two separate Uppy instances

good luck